# Simulate low bandwidth in android

Tags: android, performance, networking

Does anyone know a possibility to simulate a low bandwidth on Android phones (i.e. EDGE or G3) while connected to WiFi?

Is there a app for this?

It it possible to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/130465) on android devices?

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Edit: I don't want to use the emulator. I need it to do **reproducible performance measurements** for my bachelor's thesis. Using UMTS is just not reproducible enough that's why I'm looking for something to simulate it.

Comment: You could probably use VPN to connect to a throttled computer. :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved the problem by slowing down the network of my PC with network simulator. Then I created a virtual wifi with win 7 and connected my phone with it.

Comment: If you're interested, you can also read my bachelor thesis (in German): http://db.tt/7cunObsm

Comment: akmalabs.com seems to be defunct

Answer (score 26):

You can also just change the **preferred network type** to **2G**.

Its not as fine-grained as throttling your bandwidth via the PC but its a lot simpler to implement.

[image]

On Android 5 Lollipop go to:

1. Settings
2. More
3. Cellular Networks
4. Preferred network type

You'll notice the change to a slower GPRS network as an `E` icon on the top status bar of the screen.

Comment: The question is about throttling WiFi connections, and not cellular networks!

Comment: Hi @mahdi. You got a better answer feel free to post it.

Comment: Unless you're on a network that still has 2G or 3G this will just take you offline these days

Answer (score 13):

you can limit bandwidth in Android emulator.

eg:

```
emulator -netspeed gsm
```

**Speeds for reference in increasing kbps:**

```
                            UP       DOWN
                      -------- ----------
    gsm   GSM/CSD         14.4       14.4
    hscsd HSCSD           14.4       57.6
    gprs  GPRS            28.8       57.6
    umts  UMTS/3G        384.0      384.0
    edge  EDGE/EGPRS     473.6      473.6
    hsdpa HSDPA         5760.0   13,980.0
    lte   LTE         58,000.0  173,000.0
    evdo  EVDO        75,000.0  280,000.0
    full  No limit           ∞          ∞
```

more:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-console

Comment: I know, but using the simulator is not an option (see my edit).

Comment: This tool is located at /sdk/tools/ instead of /sdk/platform-tools. I had trouble finding it.

Answer (score 6):

Within the Android emulator, you can now throttle the network speed directly.

[image]
[image: Android Emulator Extended Controls]

Press the 3 dots button, followed by 'Cellular' on the left. You can then select the network type and signal strength.

**Speeds for reference in increasing kbps:**

```
                        UP       DOWN
                  -------- ----------
gsm   GSM/CSD         14.4       14.4
hscsd HSCSD           14.4       57.6
gprs  GPRS            28.8       57.6
umts  UMTS/3G        384.0      384.0
edge  EDGE/EGPRS     473.6      473.6
hsdpa HSDPA         5760.0   13,980.0
lte   LTE         58,000.0  173,000.0
evdo  EVDO        75,000.0  280,000.0
full  No limit           ∞          ∞
```

Answer (score 5):

If your developing on OS X, you can use [Network Link Conditioner](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?q=Network%20Link%20Conditioner) to slow down your internet connection, then turn on internet sharing and connect the Android phone to that network.

Comment: I'd just like to second how brilliant this little tool is, I use it all the time.

Comment: yeah, it takes literally 2 seconds and it's a no brainer

Answer (score 3):

You can use followed 2 applications for your purposes:

- Use **Connectify** application to create virtual WiFi AP on your PC. [Connectify link](http://www.connectify.me/)
  It will give you ability to manage traffic  over virtual adapter.
- Download **DummyNet** open source program and install service to your virtual AP [dowload dummynet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/)

Now you can connect with android to your virtual WiFi AP and manage BW + packet loss + latency by using some scripts (single batch file `*.bat`). Here is example:

```
cd C:\ipfw3-2012\binary
@echo on
@set CYGWIN=nodosfilewarning

@ipfw -q flush
@ipfw -q pipe flush

set download="80Kbit/s"

set srcIp=111.111.222.222

ipfw pipe 1 config bw %download%

ipfw add pipe 1 tcp from any to any in

ipfw -c show
ipfw pipe show
```

It works great. Here is print screen:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have an iPhone with developer mode on, you can use the network conditioner under developer settings. Setup a wi-fi hotspot and connect your android device to the hotspot. Now you can simulate the different network speeds via link conditioner.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old channel, but I was recently required to do this, most of the solutions listed seemed "quite complex" for a humble app developer like me, so I figured out a simple 3-step approach to do this.

1. Root your phone, there are a lot of websites devoted to this kind of nonsense.
2. Download [BradyBound](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oxplot.bradybound&hl=en) app. Rate this guy a 5 star for such an amazing job.
3. While connected to the desired WiFi network, throttle your connection away!

Comment: Did you find a way to limit upload speed?

Comment: Well I have started using Charles to throttle my connection now, so i stopped looking further into it. You can use Charles to throttle both upload and download speeds.

Answer (score 2):

- traffic shaper on your wireless router?
- http://code.google.com/p/netsentry/updates/list (issue 32)
- [How to use iptables in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658619/how-to-use-iptables-in-an-android-application)
- physically cover the wireless antenna on your device in order to simulate increased attenuation? :-)
- maybe proxy type software as suggested previously

Answer (score 1):

If you have rooted phone, you can use `tc` utility to limit bandwidth on `wlan0` interface. I've written a little script that does that and described how to use it on my [blog](http://dodotrivia.blogspot.com/2013/09/limiting-bandwidth-on-rooted-android.html). I've tested it with CyanogenMod 10.3 and I'm really curious if it works on other rooted phones.

Comment: I tried that in a Genymotion emulator and got this: `Android does not support qdisc 'ffff:'`.  Maybe for others it will work.

Comment: it's a paid feature in genymotion

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- In "Developer options" of your device set "Network download rate limit" under "Networking" category to desired speed.
- Use "NetThrottle - Network Tool" app from Google Play Store or similar apps which create local VPN on the device and runs all traffic through that.

Answer (score -2):

You can write a wrapper class that fetches the whole content and
returns that data with delays and only in small chunks.

Comment: A wrapper class for what? The HTTP client?

Comment: yes. either that or you write a helper class that in production code just delivers the data from the Httpclient and for debugging purposes delivers "slows" data down. might be easier to develop since you only would need to implement one function ( productin and debugging ).