# Simulate Slow Internet Connection on a REAL device?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking, android-internet

I need to test my application in conditions where even 2G Internet connectivity isn't at its full coverage (i.e. 2 bars instead of 4, 2G).

I prefer conducting these tests over WiFi.

Is there a way (programmatically or otherwise) to tell the Android OS on the **real** device to slow down or throttle Internet connection 56 Kbit/s?

Note: I know how to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8693184) on the [emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7026341). I'm looking for a way to do this on a **real device**.

Is this possible?

Comment: Check your router settings for a bandwith limiter; sometimes there's one available.

Comment: @minitech Thanks. Any idea where bandwith limiter (for **WiFi**) can be found on a DD-WRT router?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one of your comments you mentioned that you have a DD-WRT router, which is really a tiny Linux box. So you may be able to get a way with the [tc](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.ratelimit.single.html) command:

```
tc qdisc add dev $DEV root handle 1: cbq avpkt 1000 bandwidth 10mbit 
tc class add dev $DEV parent 1: classid 1:1 cbq rate 512kbit allot 1500 prio 5 bounded isolated 
tc filter add dev $DEV parent 1: protocol ip prio 16 u32 match ip dst 195.96.96.97 flowid 1:1
```

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on what you have on the upstream side.  If you're transmitting some kind of test load, write a driver at the upstream end that does, in fact, slow itself down -- although sleep() is a bad choice.  What you'll be writing is essentially a fairly hard real-time program if you hope to get anything resembling a real workload.

(When I say "a driver" btw , I don't mean necessarily a device driver, just some kind of driver program.)

But are you really trying to simulate a *slow* connection, or a degraded and noisy connection that has a low effective data rate?

Comment: Any code **inside the application to be tested** that attempts to simulate slowness sort of defeats the purpose (ever heard of Heisenberg principle?). As for your question, ideally I would like to be able to simulate both a `slow connection` and a `degraded and noisy connection` that has a low effective data rate. But for now I'm willing to compromise for slow connection only. Do you know of an app that loads the Internet connection similar to what `CPU Burn-in` for Windows does for CPU?