# Faking a slow connect with TcpClient and Socket

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp, integration-testing

I'm attempting to write an integration test to prove that a TCP client will correctly time out if an attempt to connect to the server is too slow. I have a `FakeServer` class that opens a `Socket` and listens for incoming connections:

```
public sealed class FakeServer : IDisposable
{
    ...

    public TimeSpan ConnectDelay
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        this.CreateSocket();
        this.socket.Listen(int.MaxValue);

        this.socket.BeginAccept(this.OnSocketAccepted, null);
    }

    private void CreateSocket()
    {
        var ip = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
        var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, Port);
        this.socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        this.socket.Bind(endPoint);
    }

    private void OnSocketAccepted(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(this.connectDelay);
        this.clientSocket = this.socket.EndAccept(asyncResult);
    }
}
```

Notice my attempt to delay the success of the connection via a call to `Thread.Sleep()`. Unfortunately, this does not work:

```
[Fact]
public void tcp_client_test()
{
    this.fakeServer.ConnectDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
    var tcpClient = new TcpClient();
    tcpClient.Connect("localhost", FakeServer.Port);
}
```

In the test above, the call to `tcpClient.Connect()` succeeds immediately, before the server-side `OnSocketAccepted` method is even called. I've had a look around the APIs and I can't see any obvious way for me to inject some server-side logic that must finish before the connection from the client is established.

Is there any way for me to fake a slow server/connection using `TcpClient` and `Socket`?

Comment: +1 for actually testing bad/slow connections unlike the rest of the ignorant world :)

Comment: You could use a tool like NetLimiter to throttle the connection. Unfortunately not free.

Comment: There are quite a few questions on the SO/SE network that cover this topic. Many are specific to browsers or a particular OS (there are at least 2 for OS X), but [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488888/simulate-slow-internet-connection-on-a-real-device), and [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/297103/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection) should have solutions you might be able to use.

Comment: Some generic solutions here as well: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/861/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-connection-for-page-load

Comment: I'm not after network tools, because this is running as an integration test.

Comment: I see no reason why you couldn't use [one of the latency simulation methods mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130354/how-do-i-simulate-a-low-bandwidth-high-latency-environment), regardless of whether it's for an integration test or not. If you set up a low-bandwidth or high-latency bridge and route the connection requests through that for the integration test, wouldn't that allow you to test what you want?

Comment: @Lese: it's possible. The thing is, I'm trying to keep my tests simple and understandable. Introducing a dependency like this will make them more difficult to read and maintain. Seems to me this should be simple to do without an external tool, but perhaps it's not.

Comment: @Kent: I'm guessing it probably _is_ possible. It just might involve more work. .NET isn't my thing, but the obvious approach would be to manually conduct a TCP handshake over raw sockets, so you can time the SYN, SYN-ACK, ACK messages as you see fit. But as I understand it, you can't send TCP data over raw sockets in Windows anymore, though I've also seen claims to the contrary. Or perhaps the WinPcap .NET wrapper could be of use here.

Comment: Wouldn't pinging a server be some sort of an assitance? Cool idea any way.

Comment: @Daniel: ping would require a separate TCP connection. That would be less firewall-friendly and wasteful given that we've already got a TCP connection open.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio comes with network emulator ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505008.aspx )